# How do I make sure a routine executes on time?

Tags: c++, windows, optimization, timer

I was trying to create an application that rotates a small picture of a hand 360 degrees over exactly 10 seconds using this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

void rotatebmp (HDC hdc_x, float q, float x0, float y0)
{
  q = (q * 0.01745333055);
  XFORM blah;
  blah.eM11 = cos(q);
  blah.eM12 = sin(q);
  blah.eM21 = -sin(q);
  blah.eM22 = cos(q);
  blah.eDx = x0 - cos(q)*x0 + sin(q)*y0;
  blah.eDy = y0 - cos(q)*y0 - sin(q)*x0;
  SetWorldTransform(hdc_x, &blah);
  return;
}

int main()
{
  float q = 0;
  HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
  HBITMAP hand = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45Hand.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  HBITMAP handmask = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Death\\My Documents\\45Hand2.bmp") ,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  while (1)
  {
    q = (q + 3.6);
    HDC hdc_x = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    SetGraphicsMode(hdc_x, GM_ADVANCED);
    SelectObject(hdc, handmask);
    rotatebmp (hdc_x, q, 850, 375);
    BitBlt(hdc_x,550,0,600,527,hdc,0,0, SRCAND);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc_x);
    hdc_x = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    SetGraphicsMode(hdc_x, GM_ADVANCED);
    SelectObject(hdc, hand);
    rotatebmp (hdc_x, q, 850, 375);
    BitBlt(hdc_x,550,0,600,527,hdc,0,0, SRCPAINT);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP,hdc_x);
    Sleep(100);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

A problem I am getting with this is that the execution is sluggish and one run of the loop takes maybe 0.06 seconds excluding `Sleep(100)`, since I timed the total and it came out to 16 seconds instead of the expected 10 seconds. How do I determine how much time has passed from the time the loop started to run? I'd figure the only way would be to use threads, and on non multi-core processors I think that might make the loop run even slower since it's splitting resources, will it? How does a command like Sleep() keep track of time? Is there an internal clock that exists on computers that it checks? If so how do I access that clock?

Comment: POSIX has `alarm` for this -- Windows probably has something similar. Google "timer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make sure a routine executes on time?

You cannot guarantee that. Because at any given time if OS gets really busy doing something (swapping, for example), it might decide not to give any CPU time to your program. If OS gets REALLY busy, your program can be left without any CPU time for 30 seconds or more.

However, you should not redraw your bitmap in a loop. That's not a precise.

Instead you should either use [GetTickCuont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [QueryPerformanceCOunter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to measure how much time has passed, or you should use [Windows Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx) so to receive notifications every N milliseconds. (If OS gets busy, you can receive notification later than you expected).

Regardless of method you decide to use, you will not be able to guarantee with 100% certainty that your program will take only 10 seconds to complete. For that you would need either real-time OS or real-mode "OS" (such us FreeDOS/MS-DOS/Adruino Board, etc).

Comment: Thanks, from your links I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article, I think I'll start there.